# Can Opensea pull and read standard metadata URI from ERC1155 NFT?

Tags: solidity, erc-1155, meta-data, contracturi

For [example](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1155.md#metadata) `https://token-cdn-domain/{id}.json`. Can Opensea and other similar clients read this kind of metadata link? Or I should override the `uri()` function like this

```
function uri(uint256 _tokenId) override public pure returns (string memory) {
     return string(
          abi.encodePacked("https://token-cdn-domain/",Strings.toString(_tokenId),".json")
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know ERC1155 is itself supported by opensea !
So you don't need to change anything incase of opensea it'll fetch the metadata automatically

Comment: According to [Opensea metadata standard](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/metadata-standards#implementing-token-uri), "When queried, this URL should in turn return a JSON blob of data with the metadata for your token.". But as ERC1155, it only returns link with {id}. SO I'm not sure if Opensea can read it or not

Comment: I've deployed many ERC1155 tokens and i could see them all on opensea! have you tried yourself

Comment: What should I set the metadata file name? Like this `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.json`?

Comment: you can start from `0.json` and move ahead with number `1.json` and `2.json`